# Sump Pit Bone Dry After Running Every 5 Minutes, How?

Tags: sump-pump

Two nights ago my pump was running every 5 minutes due to heavy rainfall. Water was pouring into the pit from the normal ground water sources (not the exit pipe).

My pump and float switch are both 6 months old, I have a bleed off hole in the recommended location. There is ample clearance around my float switch, nothing can conceivably touch it, it can't get stuck on anything.

The pit typically half-fills, then the pump takes it down to a few inches, maybe 2.

I checked on the pump today, (2 days after the on and off night) and the pit is dry. Like still damp, but no standing water in the pit.

How is this possible? Has my switch already failed? It's just been 30 hours since water was pouring in, could I possibly have gotten the pump to kick on with the last ounce of entering water, then had the damp basement air dry the or completely over the past day?

The pump and switch still work, I just tested it.

What should I be concerned with?

**EDIT**

As a test, I poured a bucket of water into the pump to add about an inch to the bottom of the sump pit (insert).

After 4 hours all the water was still there.

After 18 hours, the water is gone!

On closer inspection, there is a small hole in the bottom of my pit, just a small triangular cut (only about 0.5" wide by 2" long). So it looks like even though I have what appears to be a normal plastic sump insert, there is, in-fact, a hole in the bottom!

Comment: Do you have a modern plastic sump barrel or something else?

Comment: Yes, modern plastic sump barrell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be concerned with wanting to be concerned about things that are not problems, if you're going to be concerned about anything, here.

Not that difficult - the local-to-your-sump-pit groundwater source level has receded below the floor of the sump pit. The groundwater has moved to refill local groundwater stores and is no longer high enough to enter your pit.

Comment: My concern is that a plumber is telling me my switch is likely defective and my pump could be on its way. There's no way for the last few inches to drain when operating normally, and it wouldn't have evaporated.

Comment: Most sumps are not (even remotely) waterproof/sealed on the bottom - it's a normal source of water entry (in addition to any pipes), and is also a place of water exit when the groundwater level recedes. The sump is typically like a rather short well, and when the groundwater level is below it, there's no water in it.

Comment: I suggest you pour in enough water to cover the bottom of the sump but not to activate the pump, and come back in 20-40 minutes (unless you want to stand there looking at it for 20-40 minutes) to see if it has either gone down or completely vanished, supporting a "sump not sealed" condition.

Comment: I've never seen a sump pit that wasn't a sealed poly barrel. Mine will hold 2" of water for months. Where are you proposing the water would leak out?

Comment: @isherwood  older sump pits in our area (before radon awareness) often have gravel bottoms and will drain when the water table is low.   I'd just get buckets of water and/or drag in the garden hose and test til I was convinced it was working properly and make educated guesses where the rest of the water goes from there.

Comment: Anticipating this suggestion I dumped a bucket of water in the pit about 2 hours ago, every drop is still there. It's a modern cement pit with a plastic insert, water enters near the top of the pit.

Comment: @GorchestopherH you may have a float switch issue then, all you can do is continue testing with water from bucket or hose until you see it pump too long and understand if the floats mechanically getting stuck or wedged somehow, or if the switch it activated is bad.

Comment: @Tyson that's what I was afraid of. I've tested it many times, but all it takes is one more malfunction and I'm dead in the water, pun intended. My fear is that my switch failed to shut off and pumped dry for hours.

Comment: @GorchestopherH if it's 120v and plug in, and your concern is it running too long, you can add a [second standalone float switch](http://www.homedepot.com/p/206055879) pretty easily, it's probably really only a Band-Aid fix tho, and be careful that it's positioned to operate correctly.

Comment: So, at the 18h mark, the water I poured in is gone again. There is a small hole in the bottom of my pit that I imagine it drained through. So, after all that, it looks like @Ecnerwal is correct after all!