# Sump Pit Not Holding Water

Tags: basement, drainage, sump-pump, sump

Moved into a new house built in the 1970's and discovered that the sump pump was not operational. I replaced the sump pump, re-attached everything, and poured water into the dry sump pit to test operation. The curious thing was that the sump pit did not retain any water. It drained the 6 or so gallons of water I poured in just a few minutes.

The bottom of the sump pit is concrete, but it is clearly porous to some degree. I guess my question is: is this cause for concern?

My suspicion is that this is not cause for concern. My reasoning is that since some sump pits are gravel, I would assume that water draining out the bottom of the pit is normal and acceptable. Zone of saturation could be low at the moment, etc.

Discussion on this [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/115196) leads me to believe that this is okay and not cause for concern but I cannot find anything addressing this specific question.

Comment: You should be able to fill it so fast it will kick on. Maybe try two buckets, or a trash can...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is good , the idea of a home sump is to remove ground water before it causes damage; you have no ground water problem. That is better than frequent pump running.  Normally ,drain tile around house perimeter bring water to the sump to remove it, so I would expect some connection to the sump.